# C++ rounding up anamoly

Tags: c++, floating-point

i am taking input in double up to 2 decimal place long and then multiplying it with 100 and storing in int .

```
double s;
cin>>s;
int p=s*100;
cout<<p;
```

however when i input a number say 285.65  i am getting a output of 28564. I cannot figure out why it is being truncated.

Comment: Check [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361261/losing-double-precision-when-multiplying-by-multiple-of-10 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041295/multiplication-of-double-with-integer-precision or ...

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question ("Is floating point math broken?"), which is about pure floating-point arithmetic. But it _is_ a duplicate of the questions that @old_mountain links to.