# What is the data type of output if i get the product of integer and double?

Tags: c++

When i declare variable in integer type and variable in double type and i get the product of them , What you expect the output will be in each type and Why ?
example :

```
int main(){
    int number_1 ;
    double number_2 ;
    cout << number_1 * number_2 ;
    cout << endl ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: "_What you expect the output will be in each type_" What do you mean by "in each type"?

Comment: Your variables are not initialized, so anything could result.

Comment: i mean by "in each type" >> the data type of the variable  e.g. int , float , double ....

Comment: `int * double= double` as the `int` will be promoted to a `double` before the operation. **Note**: you need to initialize your variables, otherwise you will have an undetermined behavior (random values).

Comment: @elmiomar It's undefined behavior, not random values.

Comment: Sounds to me like a question from an exam

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux actually it's a random value: `int a;` reserves a space for an integer. If the value at that location is not initialized, `i` will hold the random value that was in that memory location when the space was reserved.

Comment: @elmiomar Undefined behavior means that, even if the program happens to output a result (which it doesn't have to), the value doesn't need to be random and the apparent values don't even have to be self-consistent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiplication of double with integer precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041295/multiplication-of-double-with-integer-precision)

Comment: @elmiomar Consider [this example](https://godbolt.org/g/cp97Xt). With Clang 6.0.0 and `-O2`, `int foo()` is optimized to always return 20 and `int bar()` to always return 30. In both cases, there is no value `x` could have that would produce those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, try it out. In general, the higher precision will take precedence. So if you have a `int` and a `double`, the `double` is higher precision, so the result will have that form.

```
int number_1 = 3;
double number_2  = 1.5;
std::cout << number_1 * number_2;

Output:
    4.5
```

Comment: Be careful here: a 64-bit `int` has more precision than a 64-bit `double`, although the latter has a larger range. You're right that the type of the result is `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the result is `double`. The rules get a bit wordy, but:

- if either of the types is `long double`, the other argument is converted to `long double` and the type of the result is `long double`
- otherwise, if either of the types is `double`, the other argument is converted to `double` and the type of the result is `double`
- otherwise, if either of the type is `float`, the other argument is converted to `float` and the type of the result is `float`

If there's no floating-point type involved, you get into the "integer promotions", which depend on fairly intimate details of the size and signedness of the arguments. Also, if the type of either argument is a scoped enumeration the other argument has to have the same type. All that's a bit too complicated to address here.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a double, as C++ simply overloads the operator to put the product in the bigger ( the one with more bits ) data type.

Comment: No, it's not the type with more bits. A 64-bit `int` multiplied by a 32-bit `float` produces a `float`.

Comment: well, i am sorry, i meant the one with more precision

Comment: As I said in comments to other answers, a 64-bit `int` has more precision than a 64-bit `double`, but a 64-bit `int` by a 64-bit `double` produces a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be double
Because in c++, when there are multiple data types, it always prints the answer in the highest precision data type.

Comment: Be careful here: a 64-bit `int` has more precision than a 64-bit `double`, although the latter has a larger range. You're right that the type of the result is `double`.